# Real time video streaming lag

Tags: python, html, opencv, flask, video-streaming

Am also working on multiple cameras I am able to process different rtsp streams on web page. But there is an issue regarding accumulation of lag. Is there a way to keep up to date with the live streams?

A screenshot of the same is attached for your reference (time highlighted in red)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaz4p.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a nasty little issue with certain ip cameras. It's especially prominent with ubiquiti cameras. The method I use to deal with it is to have a separate thread (use multiprocess for python) pulling frames faster than the camera framerate and pushing it in to a circular buffer. Then whenever you need a new frame, you pull from the buffer head, not the camera.

Comment: Thanks @Ian for replying. As you suggested let me try multiprocessing to pull frames.